Exception thrown from convex_decomposition_3() with valid Nef
tldr; I don't know what I'm doing. My nef seems to be valid, can't find any issues, but I'm getting errors when trying to do convex decomp on it. I'm hoping to figure out where I can look to find out what I might be doing wrong.
I've just started working with CGAL, so forgive me if I'm clueless. I'm trying write a function to take in a .obj file and perform convex decomposition on it. I can do the file IO, convert it to a Nef_polyhedron_3, and verify that the polyhedron is valid with nef.is_valid(), but I get the following error when I try to decompose it:
CGAL error: assertion violation!
Expression : sf_old->mark()
File       : C:\dev\CGAL\include\CGAL/Convex_decomposition_3/SM_walls.h        
Line       : 560
Explanation:
Refer to the bug-reporting instructions at https://www.cgal.org/bug_report.html

The lines surrounding this assertion (553-563) are:
if(split_sface) {
  if(cap1->incident_sface() == cap2->incident_sface()) {
    SFace_handle sf_new = this->new_sface();
    SFace_handle sf_old = cap1->incident_sface();

    CGAL_NEF_TRACEN("sf_new->mark()=" << sf_old->mark());
    sf_new->mark() = sf_old->mark();
    CGAL_assertion(sf_old->mark());
    link_as_face_cycle(se_new, sf_new);
    link_as_face_cycle(se_new->twin(), sf_old);
}

I'm struggling to understand this specific problem, but it raises another question that I have: What are the conditions under which a valid Nef_polyhedron_3 will throw errors or otherwise fail when passed into convex_decomposition_3()?
What I've tried, code, etc.
I'm reading from a .obj file to a polygon soup, then repairing, orienting, and converting to a polygon mesh, after which my program indicates that the polyhedron is valid. From there, trying duplicating manifold vertices, then converting to a nef, after which my program indicates that the nef is valid and 2-manifold. When passed to convex_decomposition_3(), I get the aforementioned CGAL error.
I've tried using other models as input and had success. I've inspected the error-inducing model and can't find any immediate errors (no noticeable holes, etc.), and of course none of the checks within the function have indicated that anything is wrong.
CGAL Version: 6.0 Release
Boost Version: 1.72.0
OS: Windows 10 64-bit
Compiler: C++: MSVC 17.10.0
Header File:
#ifndef VCXCMP
#define VCXCMP
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>

#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel.h>

#include <CGAL/IO/OBJ.h>
#include <CGAL/Polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Nef_polyhedron_3.h>
#include <CGAL/Nef_3/SNC_indexed_items.h>

#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/repair.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/orient_polygon_soup.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/repair_polygon_soup.h>
#include <CGAL/Polygon_mesh_processing/polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh.h>

#include <CGAL/convex_decomposition_3.h>

typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_exact_constructions_kernel Kernel;
typedef CGAL::Polyhedron_3<Kernel> Polyhedron;
typedef CGAL::Nef_polyhedron_3<Kernel, CGAL::SNC_indexed_items> NefPolyhedron;
typedef NefPolyhedron::Volume_const_iterator NefConstIter;
typedef Kernel::Point_3 Point;

using namespace std;
bool loadPolyhedron(string filename, Polyhedron &poly)

#endif

.cpp file:
#include "ConvexDecomp.hpp"
using namespace std;

bool loadPolyhedron(string filename) {
    vector<vector<size_t>> polygons;
    vector<Point> points;

    ifstream modelIn(filename);
    CGAL::IO::read_OBJ(modelIn, points, polygons);
    cout << "Loaded polygon \"" << filename << "\" successfully" << endl;

    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::orient_polygon_soup(points, polygons);
    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::repair_polygon_soup(points, polygons);
    CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::polygon_soup_to_polygon_mesh(points, polygons, poly);

    size_t vert_dupes = CGAL::Polygon_mesh_processing::duplicate_non_manifold_vertices(poly);

    if (poly.is_valid()) {
        cout << "Polyhedron is valid" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cerr << "ERROR: Polyhedron is invalid" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    NefPolyhedron nef(poly);

    cout << "Is 2-Manifold = " << (nef.is_simple() ? "True" : "False") << endl;

    if (nef.is_valid(false)) {
        cout << "Nef polyhedron is valid" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cerr << "ERROR: Nef polyhedron is invalid" << endl;
        return false;
    }

    CGAL::convex_decomposition_3(nef);
    cout << "Decomposed polygon \"" << filename << "\" sucessfuly" << endl;

    vector<Polyhedron> convex_parts;
    NefConstIter ci = ++nef.volumes_begin();
    for (; ci != nef.volumes_end(); ++ci) {
        if (ci->mark()) {
            Polyhedron P;
            nef.convert_inner_shell_to_polyhedron(ci->shells_begin(), P);
            convex_parts.push_back(P);
        }
    }

    cout << "Decomposition into " << convex_parts.size() << " convex parts " << endl;
    return true;
}

